# Safe ways to clean the BizTalk tracking database?

Tags: sql-server, biztalk, biztalk-2010

We have a Biztalk Server 2010 with a very large tracking database BizTalkDTADb (~ 200 GB).

For a long period of time (~2 years) the job DTA Purge and Archive hadn't been run at all.

1. We ran the job DTA Purge and Archive on a copy of the BizTalk database. The task was fulfilled successfully. However, the size of the database Biztalk **increased to 217 GB**.
2. Then on the other copy of the database Biztalk we launched the procedure dtasp_PurgeTrackingDatabase (we have the dump). However, it did not bring any results. The database size increased again.

```
declare @ dtLastBackup datetime 
set @ dtLastBackup = GetUTCDate () 
exec dtasp_PurgeTrackingDatabase 0, 30, 31, @ dtLastBackup
```

Can you recommend any safe ways to clean the database BizTalkDTADb?

Is it possible to create a new database BizTalkDTADb, attach it to an existing group, and detach the old one from the group?

How can you truncate the BizTalkDTADb tables in Biztalk Server 2010?

Comment: I suspect that all of the extra space is in your Transaction Log; Try doing a Transaction Log backup followed by a Shrink of your Transaction Log file. Bear in mind that SQL Server likes to hold-on to disk-space where it can so it doesn't need to allocate space, which is a costly operation by comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By following the instructions from Microsoft http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561918.aspx and use the dtasp_PurgeAllCompletedTrackingData stored procedure